# Pulling a dir and all its contents from every client on a domain and copy to file share?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, active-directory, copy

I am looking to copy a bunch of dir's "C:\Users\userOne\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates" and all of their contents onto a share with the folder being named the client and the user name.

I am sure a for loop is the best way to go about this but I am hung up on what variables to use to get what I want.

The array will surely contain a list of every workstation on the AD, but I need to specify a bunch of directories per workstation. Maybe a wildcard like this will work? C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates

I've seen tons of useful examples on here but most of them involve copying from one location to many instead of my situation where its from many to one.

This is my first post, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I am not sure I get what you want entirely, you say bunch of directories, are the directories the user directories, or directories within each user profile?

Comment: its one specific directory in each user folder. i.e.
C:\Users\USERONE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates
C:\Users\USERTWO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates
C:\Users\USETHREE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates

Comment: Here is an example. nothing is copied, it just prints to screen. line 1: `@echo off` then line 2: `set "dirs=AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates\"` finally line 3: `for /f "skip=1tokens=1*" %%i in ('wmic UserAccount get Name') do if exist "%homedrive%\users\%%~i\%dirs%" echo "%homedrive%\users\%%~i\%dirs%"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `...\*\...` in a wildcard-based path to represent all directories at a given level of a directory hierarchy.

In your scenario, you could so something like the following (using a local path on a single machine for simplicity) - be sure to run the command *elevated* (as *administrator*) so you're permitted to access other users' home directories:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates |
  Select-Object @{ name='User'; expression={ ($_.FullName -split '\\')[2] } }, FullName |
    ForEach-Object { 
      Copy-Item -WhatIf -Recurse -Force -LiteralPath $_.FullName "\\some\share\$($_.User)" 
    }
```

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) `C:\Users\*\...` implicitly loops over all user home directories and returns the directory at the specified remaining path for each, if present.
- The [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call transforms the [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances emitted by `Get-ChildItem` into custom objects with `.FullName` (the full directory path) and `.User` properties (the username implied by the path), by way of a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties).
- The [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call then uses [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) to copy each directory to a destination directory on the target share named for the user; `-Recurse` copies the directory and all its contents (the directory's whole subtree), and `-Force` includes hidden items that would be excluded by default.

  - The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the `Copy-Item` command *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.